# Simple web-scraping code won't run but no error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, web-scraping

First post here! I can't seem to get this code to work

[python script on VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKRRD.png)

All I did was try to work step by step with this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvCBzhhydNk

https://github.com/Vidito/webscraping_housing/blob/main/main.py

but when I run the code, the terminal just gives me nothing (please check image). I am baffled and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= "https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam?ac=1"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('section', class_="listing-search-item")

for list in lists:
    title = list.find('a', class_="listing-search-item__link--title").text.replace('\n', '')
    location = list.find('div', class_="listing-search-item__location").text.replace('\n', '')
    price = list.find('span', class_="listing-search-item__price").text.replace('\n', '')
    area = list.find('span', class_="illustrated-features__description").text.replace('\n', '')
    
    info = [title, location, price, area]
    print(info)```

Nana
````

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Please format your code properly. Without proper formatting it's impossible to tell if you may have errors in it - especially indentation issues

Comment: @LancelotduLac Thank you for your comment! the code is also in the last link I posted, but I am trying to figure out how to make it look right in the post. Sorry!

Comment: just add three Highcommas in front of your code and finish your example with 3 highcommas asa well :)

Comment: @y.y Thank you!!!

Comment: You may want to try *selenium* for this. That page is constructed primarily with JavaScript which means that it's incomplete as far as BeautifulSoup is concerned. The result is that the section tag you're looking for doesn't actually exist until all the JS has executed

Comment: @LancelotduLac Thank you so much for your help! I will look that up.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't print anything, because the find_all function doesn't find anything. The class for the section is called "listing-search-item listing-search-item--list listing-search-item--for-rent" not only listing-search-item. You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match everything that starts with what you have right now.

*Don't use "list" as a variable name, there is already a built-in function called list.*

Comment: Thank you! I will doublecheck the source since it seems like some things changes since the tutorial was made.

Comment: @LancelotduLac I never said to specify all classes? I am saying that it searches for exact matches only and they are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have run across `fairlane` before you get the texts from the site `https://www.pararius.com/apartments/amsterdam`, it's in order to check whether you a robot.

You can add `print(soup)` after `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')`. You will find the outputs were not you are looking for.